# Uncaught exception handler and application context

Tags: android

I have uncaught exception handler & in time T in handles uncaught exception - in my implementation it needs a context because of I'm saving network state information, and now is the question: where I should get the context?

I thought that the solution is something like in Application class in static var save a instance of application context & then use it, but what will be in case of uncaught exception? Will that instance of context be valid?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar and am passing in the Activity context in my onCreate() method of the activity.  For an uncaught exception I dump the stack trace to an XML file.  When the app restarts I look for the existence of that dump file and prompt the user to e-mail it to me :)